# There exist a name for multi-variable polynomials such that all of there exponents are equal to 1?

Tags: polynomials, definition

I mean, a polynomial of the form:

$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=c_{1,\ldots,n}x_1x_2 \dots x_n+c_{1,\ldots,n-1}x_1x_2\dots x_{n-1}+\dots+c_1x_1+\dots+c_nx_n+c.$

I was tempted to call them square-free (but I know that means something else already for some people) or maybe free of squares (but kind of the same problem).

Thanks.

Comment: I don’t think that there’s an established name. Are you in a situation where these things come up naturally?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to generalize some results from polynomials of the form $\det(Diag(x_1,\ldots,x_n)-A)$ where A is a matrix. So I am just trying to figure out if I have to do my own definition.